# Remove translucent background from Android activity

Tags: java, android

How I can remove the translucent effect from my app ? When I start my app I see a transparency on the border left and right , also I see this effect on toolbar. I tried using

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
```

but not work.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the effect?

Comment: is this from a style file?  Does it have a parent theme?  What about your manifest? A screenshot would help as well.

Comment: It's a part of the manifest file. The theme is AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.